# SQL CH calculate size in bytes for select

Tags: sql, clickhouse

How I can get the size in bytes for the results of the SQX query?
For example, I want to know how many bytes are in the column value. How i can obtain this info by SQL query? I use Clickhouse DB

```
SELECT value, name 
FROM stage.log
WHERE date  >= '2023-02-04' and   date < '2023-02-07')
AND (name = 'apple' )
```

Comment: Try to sum the result of the [byteSize](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions#bytesize) function calls.